# NSButton + & - Button

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

In my application, i need to add + & - button to add and delete the row from a table, 
I tried to find out any default image/ button but didn't get , Proper images for + & - button, 
Do i need to arrange these buttons image by my own or its available in the Cocoa framework. 
Thanks again for looking at question, probably silly question doesn't it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are system-provided images for this, named `NSAddTemplate` and `NSRemoveTemplate`. You can enter those names into the image field for your buttons in Interface Builder, or alternatively use these constants to access the images programmatically:

```
[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameAddTemplate];
[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameRemoveTemplate];
```

Comment: These are only available since Leopard, by the way, so if, for some reason, you're still supporting Tiger or earlier, you'll need to bundle the images into your app and load them by name using `imageNamed:`. Back in the day, I created a plus and minus image pair for exactly this purpose: http://boredzo.org/plusminus/

Comment: Thanks rob & peter, my app will be running on the leopord only

Comment: Tried to find this in early 2018. It's now called `init?(named: NSImage.Name)` in `NSImage`.