# NSButton pair +/- rounded, like Finder?

Tags: macos, nsbutton

This question [NSButton + & - Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730090/nsbutton-button) answers how to make those [+|-] buttons for adding/removing things, like in tables, using a gradient button and system supplied + and - images. You still get two separate square buttons, while Finder has a nicely paired set of those buttons, see image:
[image]
They are clearly paired. How do you make those?

Comment: This is `NSSegmentedControl` see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523078/location-of-add-delete-buttons-for-an-nstableview-in-os-x/52242289#52242289

Comment: If you make it an answer instead of a comment I can credit you :-)